# Prove that $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{xy^2(y+z)} \le {1 \over 2} \sqrt{(x + y + z)^4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove the following inequality for all positive real numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$:
> $$\sqrt{xy^2(y+z)} + \sqrt{yz^2(x+z)} + \sqrt{zx^2(x+y)} \le {1 \over 2} \sqrt{(x + y + z)^4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2}$$

**My attempt**. I tried to prove it myself but I didn't know how to. I tried to transform this inequality but made it even more complicated. Is there an easy way to prove it? Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You may give more information, e.g. source, background etc. Also, you may give more details of your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's raise both sides of the inequality to the second power. Indeed, we just need to show:

$$2(\sqrt {xy^2(y+z)}\sqrt {yz^2(x+z)}+\sqrt {yz^2(x+z)}\sqrt {zx^2(x+y)}+\sqrt {xy^2(y+z)}\sqrt {zx^2(x+y)})\le x^3y+xz^3+y^3z+x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2+2x^2yz+2xy^2z+2xyz^2.$$

Now, notice that: $$2\sqrt {xy^2(y+z)}\sqrt {yz^2(x+z)}\le yz[x(y+z)+y(x+z)]=2xy^2z+xyz^2+y^2z^2.$$

Hence, it suffices to prove that:

$$x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2\le x^3y+xz^3+y^3z; $$

and, this is almost obvious because;

$$(x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2)^2\le (x^3y+xz^3+y^3z)(xyz^2+xy^2z+x^2yz).$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, but could you please explain your solution in more detail?

Comment: @JackBlack You're welcome. The first step (the second power) was a simple calculation. The second step was done by AM-GM. Then based on being cyclic, I reached the third step. To make sure, you can add all the terms together and verify the result. Finally, the last line is an application of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @JackBlack Moreover, instead of those terms containing radicals, I put $2xy^2z+xyz^2+y^2z^2$ (because of the inequality in the second line) and then added all the terms ...